# Can external user provisioning be used with Community user licenses?

Tags: community, connected-apps, identity

Given a Community User, once a field on the user's Contact record is set to a given value, the community user needs to be provisioned as a user in Google GSuite (probably "for Education" or "for Non-profit" flavor, but the client has not yet signed up for GSuite).

From [User Provisioning for Connected Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_user_provisioning.htm&type=5) in Salesforce Help:

> Here’s a user provisioning scenario. You configure user provisioning for a G Suite connected app in your org. Then you assign the Employees profile to that connected app. When you create a user in your org and assign the user to the Employees profile, the user is provisioned in G Suite. When the user is deactivated, or the profile assignment changes, the user is deprovisioned from G Suite.

This sounds tailor-made for our use case, as we could assign a new profile when the contact record is updated.  However, the text says "when you create a user in your org", which might imply "internal user" (Salesforce License).  I can't find any documentation that clarifies whether or not a community user profile can be assigned to a connected app in this way, and if so, if it would work with external user provisioning in this way, or if is it limited to a particular type of community user license.